# When would combining columns into a single, delimited column be better in a RDB schema?

Tags: sql, database, schema, relational-database, normalization

Consider for example the case where you have two peaces of data, where one value is rarely used without the other.  As one example, here is a table holding user authentication data :

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
auth_name STRING,
auth_password STRING,
auth_password_salt STRING
)
```

I think that password is meaningless without salt, and the other way around.  I also have the option on representing the data this way:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
auth_name STRING,
auth_secret STRING,
)
```

And in `auth_secret`, store strings such as `D5SDfsuuAedW:unguessable42`

In general, are there any situations where combining columns into one, delimited column would be a better choice?

Even if it is never a "better choice" overall, are there any *costs* (performance, space, anything) to having more columns vs fewer columns (for the same data)?  My motivation is better understanding and to be able to more competently argue against it when someone suggests this sort of thing.

---

--***edited*** I changed the example... original example as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE points
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
x_coordinate INT,
y_coordinate INT,
z_coordinate INT
)
```

vs

```
CREATE TABLE points
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
position STRING
)
```

In `position`, storing strings such as `7:3:15`

Comment: No, I don't see any reason to ever do that... Easy to combine, not so easy to split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible answer to this question is *never*. Never, ever, store delimited data in a column. It defeats the entire point of columns, which are there to delimit your data, and makes it inordinately difficult to do anything that a database has been designed to do. It's a violation of normalisation so huge that you'll spend hours on Stack Overflow trying to correct it in a months time.

#### Never do this.

However, "never say never".

In certain, extremely limited, circumstances it's okay. Never assume it's okay but it *can* be.

A good example is Stack Overflow's own [Posts table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/99472), which stores the tags in a delimited format for quick *reading*. The tags a question has are read from the database far more often than they are edited. The tags are stored in a separate table, PostTags, and then denormalised to Posts when they are updated.

In short, even though you can denormalise your data in this way, don't. Try everything possible to avoid it. If you come across a situation where you've been optimizing for days and the only way to get something quicker is to denormalize, then it's okay. Just ensure that you are only ever going to *read* data from that column and you have a secondary process in place to ensure that it is kept up-to-date. If the update of the denormalised data fails, roll everything back to ensure that your data is consistent.

Comment: Accepting this answer for most closely following the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You do that when there is no chance of needing to join, query, report or aggregate the data.

In other words - never. It is bad database design.

First Normal form (NF1) states that attributes should be distinct - it is the basic requirement.

Comment: My example might be bad, since each coordinate can actually have value on its own (for join, query etc as you said).  If I could think of an example where one thing literally had no meaning without the other, would there be any advantage whatsoever (space, performance, anything?) to rolling them up?

Comment: @derekv - The advantages (if any) would be completely overrun by the disadvantages - sorting, querying, aggregating and reporting would be much more difficult and require you to _parse_ the field first. You will also have problems optimizing and indexing.

Comment: I disagree slightly see my answer and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/99472 :-)

Comment: The relational model allows types to be arbitrarily complex. It just requires the dbms to either ignore the complexity (treat the value as a black box, returning it and updating it in toto), or to provide functions to manipulate the parts (as every SQL dbms does with functions to manipulate dates and timestamps).

Answer (score 1):

You left out a significant option: create an appropriate user-defined data type. ([PostgreSQL has long had an intrinsic data type for 2-space](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6473).)

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtype.html)
- [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i46376)
- [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx)
- [DB2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008476.html)

These implementations differ quite a lot.

But you might not have the luxury of using one of those platforms. You might have to use MySQL, for example, which doesn't support user-defined data types.

Relational theory says that data types can be arbitrarily complex; they can have internal structure. The most common data type that has internal structure is the type "date".  Relational theory specifies what the dbms is supposed to do with data types like that. The dbms must either

- ignore the internal structure entirely, or
- provide functions to manipulate the parts.

In the case of dates, every SQL dbms provides functions to manipulate the parts.

You can make a good argument for a single column that stores 3-space coordinates like "7:3:15" in MySQL. To keep in line with relational theory, you'd want the dbms to ignore the structure, and return only the single value "7:3:15"; manipulation of parts is left to application code.

One problem with *implementing* something like that in MySQL is that MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. So it's a lot harder to prevent values like "wibble:frog:foo" from finding their way into the database.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, it seems to be an important aspect to this problem.